# Unity/Vuforia/C# : change a TextMesh text makes it disappear

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm trying to use Unity and Vuforia framework with some C# scripts. The aim is to recognize images, print a 3D model, and some informations about the image around the target (4 3D text, inserted into a prefab).
With Vuforia, i just have to drag n drop a prefab target iunto the scene, and add as his child the 3D model and the prefab containing the UI Text.

This part always works, i've no problem to see the model and the text with de fault value hellow world.

But to set the text, i've attached to the target a script implementing the vuforia interface to know when the target is recognized.

If the script is triggered, i get the UI prefab, get all his components (4 TextMesh from 3D objects) and set it into a thread (because values i want to set are from HTTP requests).
Following the code :

```
        while (Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive)
        { 
            values = thingworxLink.getValues();   
            index = 0;

            TextMesh[] ts = new TextMesh[4];
            ts = prefabUI.GetComponentsInChildren<TextMesh>();
            print("before set");
            foreach (TextMesh t in ts)
            {
                t.text = values[index]+" "+units[index];

                print("text[" + index + "]=" + t.text);
                index++;
            }

            print("after set");

        }
```

Each time into the textmesh.text i see the right values. But after the first set, instead of seeing "hello world" disappear and the value appear, the text just disappear...
I tried some ways but didn't find a solution about the problem, and as the framework need the camera, i can't simulate it on unity currently...

Dooes anyone know how to fix this problem ? maybe a code fail ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is commonly wrong to do threading in unity. Use WWW class for http request instead. I would think your thread does not update the main thread UI but more likely a copy of it that is ignored by the system.

Comment: I use the www class for the http request (from the thingworxlink class, which does the work). But the time to get all the time it works for the http request, the camera freeze (it's not really bad with a good connection, but what if i have a bad download speed ... Is there a way to do this in a thread like way ? )

Comment: I changed the UI communication in he main thread, just keeping the httprequest in the thread ! it works fine. Thanks for the tips about threads and unity !

Comment: Fact is that Unity cannot support thread in the way you would use it in ASP.NET or other .NET application. This is why it offers coroutines for asynchronous running. Using WWW class from UnityEngine and you get the fake multi-threading without all the pb of it. From what I read, Unity only allows thread when passing value type object. So you can work on collection of Vector3 for pathfinding for instance, but modifying the UI is failing as you saw it.